# How is the height of a component related to its skin file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning, spark-skinning

I have a panel with a custom skin whose height is smaller than its hostcomponent's height. When I layout this out in a vgroup, the component's size doesn't reflect the skin's smaller size.

Is there a way to completely delegate the size of a container to the skin class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set component's `minHeight` or `measuredMinHeight` in `measure()` to the desired size.